# How to check if JAVA_HOME is too old?

Tags: batch-file, java-home

I want to check if JAVA_HOME is set and if it is older than JAVA 10. How to check it correctly ? I must have this check inside this if statement. This script does not detect JAVA version.

```
set EXPECTED_JAVA_VERSION=10

if not defined "%JAVA_HOME%" (
    for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
        set JAVAVER=%%g
    )
    set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:"=%
    echo JAVAEVER%JAVAVER%
    for /f "delims=. tokens=2" %%v in ("%JAVAVER%") do (
    
       set JAVA=%%v
       goto loaded_version
    )
    :loaded_version
    echo "%JAVA%"
    IF "%JAVA%" LSS "%EXPECTED_JAVA_VERSION%" (echo WRONG JAVA VERSION) ELSE (echo CORRECT JAVA VERSION)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `delims` and `tokens` correcty, no need to set so many variables either:

```
@echo off
set "EXPECTED=10"
for /f tokens^=2*delims^=.^" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /LIC:"java version"') do if "%%i" lss "%EXPECTED%" echo Wrong version & goto :EOF
echo Correct Version!
```

Answer (score 0):

Within  the `code block` from the `(` of the original `if` to the very closing `)`,

1. labels are essentially illegal.
2. `%var%` means the value of `var` at the time the block was encountered, not the value as changed within the block.
3. You need to invoke `delayedexpansion` to access the value of a variable that has changed.

Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

`if not defined "%JAVA_HOME%" (` asks whether the variable `"%JAVA_HOME%"` is defined, so if `java_home` is set to `c:\somewhere` then `if not defined "%JAVA_HOME%" (` will be interpreted as `if not defined "c:\somewhere" (`. It's highly unlikely that a variable named `"c:\somewhere"` has been defined, and not what you probably want.

This is a revised version which circumvents the problems - I believe. Since you don't show us the string produced by `java -version`, I don't know the detail of processing it.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set EXPECTED_JAVA_VERSION=10

if not defined JAVA_HOME (
    for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
        set "JAVAVER=%%g"
    )
    set "JAVAVER=!JAVAVER:"=!"
    echo JAVAEVER!JAVAVER!
    set "JAVA="
    for /f "delims=. tokens=2" %%v in ("!JAVAVER!") do (
     set "JAVA=%%v"
    )
    echo "!JAVA!"
)
IF "%JAVA%" LSS "%EXPECTED_JAVA_VERSION%" (echo JAVA VERSION is %JAVA% - need %expected_java_version%) ELSE (echo CORRECT JAVA VERSION)
```

If `java_home` is not defined, then do the following:

- find the version of java from the third token of the string passed by `findstr` and assign to `javaver`.
- using `delayed expansion` remove quotes from the now-changed value of `javaver`. (Note that if `%%g` is a string "enclosed in quotes" then `%%~g` would have already removed those enclosing quotes.
- again `echo` the result.
- "set" the value of `java` to *nothing*, which undefines `java`.
- set the value of `java` from the string in `javaver`
- display the result

Then it's a simple comparison - and please take the opportunity to produce an explanatory message.

**BUT** having done all this, I'd suggest that if `java_home` is not defined, then `java` is not installed at all, and you actually need to run your test if java **IS** installed, which implies `java_home` would be set.